# Network Error AxiosError: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:105169:14)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios, stripe-payments

I am building an Amazon clone and have implemented Payment through stripe and now after entering card details, it redirects to the orders page (which I want it to) but then it shows this "Network Error AxiosError: Network Error     at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:105169:14)" on the screen and when I open stripe to see it shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KXP1.png)

These are my code files

**Payment.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Payment.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import axios from "./axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge the customer

    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
      });
      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
      //Stripe Expects total in currency subunits
    };

    getClientSecret();
  }, [basket]);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ payment }) => {
        //paymentIntent = Payment Confirmation
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_BASKET",
        });

        navigate("/orders", { replace: true });
        //Here instead of push we have used replace because after successful payment we dont want to come back to the payments page
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    //Listen for changes in the Card Element and display any errors the customer makes while entering the card details
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout (<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} Items</Link>)
        </h1>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__address">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
            <p>76/4A Rajpur Road</p>
            <p>Dehradun</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review Items & Delivery</h3>
          </div>

          <div className="payment__items">
            {basket.map((item) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                rating={item.rating}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>

          <div className="payment__details">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />

              <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => <h3>Order Total : {value}</h3>}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeparator={true}
                  prefix={"$"}
                />
                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>

              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import Header from "./Header";
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import Payment from "./Payment";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import Orders from "./Orders";

const promise = loadStripe(
  "pk_test_51NRKdkSGdggXhtrctnXw7BsWnkeXoSwRsRYKxZ7o17Nqx55wvPdMQJwSpm4BCXZoSPiIFW9KOrPAFAwoUylvfEt100BhWELocF"
);

function App() {
  const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    //Will only rum once the app component loads
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      console.log("The user is : ", authUser);

      if (authUser) {
        //The user was Logged In / The user just Logged In

        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser,
        });
      } else {
        //The user was logged out

        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/orders"
            element={
              <>
                <Header />
                <Orders />
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route
            path="/checkout"
            element={
              <>
                <Header />
                <Checkout />
              </>
            }
          ></Route>

          <Route
            path="/payment"
            element={
              <>
                <Header />
                <Elements stripe={promise}>
                  <Payment />
                </Elements>
              </>
            }
          ></Route>

          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <>
                <Header />
                <Home />
              </>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js (Backend)**

```
/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
 * const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 *
 */

const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

// exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
//   logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_51NRKdkSGdggXhtrcB8ZbigCqipRaMbRZVIJGYGGhAr7tM9fkCqXMaBJL7ubJhfxgDfxaPhYxG3nrtUarNhvhQ76U00zgF0sXPa"
);

//API

//App Config
const app = express();

//Middleware
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// API Routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;

  console.log("Payment Request Received BOOM!!! for this amount -> ", total);

  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: total,
      currency: "usd",
    });

    // Send the client secret as a response
    response.status(201).send({
      clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.response.data);
    response.status(500).send({
      error: "An error occurred while creating the payment intent.",
    });
  }
});

// Listen Command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

//http://127.0.0.1:5001/challenge-940e1/us-central1/api
```

**axios.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/challenge-940e1/us-central1/api", //The API (cloud Function) URL
});

export default instance;
```

I have showcased my whole problem above

Comment: You shouldn't share the Stripe Secret key (sk_test_xxx) here. It should be kept private, even if it's only a Test mode key.

Your error seems related to axios config. Have you tried modifying the baseURL from 127.0.0.1 to localhost?

Comment: How do I do that, please dont mind I'm an absolute newbie here, also If I change the baseURL to localHost wouldn't the project path get lost i.e "challenge-940e1/us-central1/api"